# Fourier descriptors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching, fft, fourier-descriptors

I'm trying to find the matching score between the boundary of shapes that do not exactly match. I use Fourier descriptor to represent these boundaries and find the similarity based on DTW as follows: `(X,Y)` is the coordinate points of the boundary sorted in clockwise order.

```
Z = complex(X, Y);
FD = fft(Z);
FD(1) = 0;
FD = FD/FD(2);
```

Then for similarity measure:

```
Dist = dtw(abs(FD1),abs(FD2));
```

The similarity result is not accurate therefore I would like to check if I applied the Fourier descriptor correctly and any recommendation of a similarity measure.

When I try `ifft` to get the shape back, the resulting shape is the reflection of the original shape. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: DTW seems like the wrong error measure. What you want to do is directly compare the first few Fourier coefficients (as the latter ones represent high-frequency changes that are mostly caused by noise).

Comment: @CrisLuengo when I select few Fourier coefficients I get the same matching result but the distance value decrease. Also, I try the Euclidean distance but it does not measure the similarity correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Note the normalizations you apply to the Fourier components:

```
FD = fft(Z);
FD(1) = 0;       % ignore translation
FD = FD/FD(2);   % normalize for size, and rotate
```

`FD(1)` is the DC component, and encodes the translation. `FD(2)` is the lowest frequency, it represents (together with `FD(end)`) a single sine + cosine component for the outline. With this component you can represent an ellipse. The phase encodes the orientation of the ellipse, the magnitude encodes the size, and the difference in magnitude between `FD(2)` and `FD(end)` represents the aspect ratio. By dividing by `FD(2)`, you normalize for size and impose a specific rotation determined only by the best fit ellipse. **This explains why your shape seemed reflected when using the IFFT, it gets rotated to some standard orientation.**

In your error measure, you compare only the magnitude of the components of the two shapes. **By ignoring the phase, you throw away a lot of what makes the shape.** For example, try plotting the IFFT of the magnitude of the Fourier descriptor. You'll see something that does not at all look like your original shape.

However, this is the common thing to do, since it is the easiest way of obtaining rotation invariance. The standardization of the orientation based on the best fit ellipse is very noise-sensitive (with noise being e.g. the location of the samples along the contour). In fact, **the value of most of the Fourier descriptor elements is very sensitive to these locations**, if the contour is sampled at different locations, the Fourier descriptor changes significantly.

Thus, ideally, the error measure takes both magnitude and phase into account (or both real and imaginary components). But, in practice, it is hard to use the phase information and people mostly compare amplitudes, even if many different shapes will thereby become similar.

Next, since `FD(1)` was set to 0 and `FD(2)` to 1, these two components are not useful. Other than that, you should look only at the first few components (let's say `n`):

```
FD(1)   % ignore, set to 0 above
FD(2)   % ignore, set to 1 above
FD(3)
FD(4)
...
FD(n+2)
```

These frequency components have a related element, which can be found at:

```
FD(1)   -> none
FD(2)   -> FD(end)
FD(3)   -> FD(end-1)
FD(4)   -> FD(end-2)
...
FD(n+2) -> FD(end-n)
```

I can imagine most people simply ignoring those, but I would certainly include them into the comparison, as they provide additional relevant information.

This leads to `2*n-1` numbers (`3:n+2` and `end-n:end`). `n` is typically 10, but do experiment with smaller values here as well.

The simplest way to compare these is to compute the **Euclidean distance**, though I'm sure other distance measures can be useful too.

---

**TL;DR:**

The `dtw` distance measure seems wrong to me, try using a normal Euclidean distance (mean square difference). Further, compare only the first ~10 components, subsequent components will add more noise than useful information. But leave out the first two elements, since these have been make useless by the normalization.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it is very helpful. When I take phase into account I found out that it depends on the rotation and starting points of the boundary. Could you please help me on how to normalize the phase to be invariant to rotation and starting points?

Comment: @drq40: that is what `FD/FD(2)` is supposed to do.

Comment: unfortunately, I extract FD for the same boundary but rotated and get a different value of the phase this is the plot of 20 coefficient using a = angle(FD); ![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/a/01wpzm4 ).

Comment: @drq40: I have edited my answer. You are right, the standardization of the orientation does not work very well unless the shape is clearly elongated.